# Compare string query in java using nashorn

Tags: java-8, nashorn

I have this code:

```
        String query = "a == someRandomWord && b != 2";

        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");

        SimpleBindings variables = new SimpleBindings();
        variables.put("a", "someRandomWord");
        variables.put("b", 1);
        System.out.println(engine.eval(query, variables));
```

It gives me an error because I'm not allowed to pass String as a parameter.

How can I compare String objects with `.eval()` function?

Comment: Wouldn't this be an error because `p` is unbound?

Comment: Unbound? I have no idea what unbound is. How to fix that?

Comment: You have two variables: `a` and `p` in comparison - yet you declared variables `a` and `b` in your simple bindings. Variable `p` is not bound anywhere, and strict version of javascript would produce a runtime error if you do that I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Point is that I want to compare if `a` is a string. Some random word. For example, is `a.equal(p)`. My bad, ill change it more clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String query = "a == p && a != 2";
                    ^^^
                    this is not a string but a variable
```

Either use `'yourString'` or `\"yourString\"` (as you need to escape it in Java), e.g.

```
String query = "a == 'someRandomWord' && b != 2";
```

Alternatively: supply also the binding for `p` as was suggested in the comments.

Comment: Oh, the problem was with the `String query`, not with the `SimpleBindings`. Thanks!